# Convert array of "key-value" pairs into object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of key and value pairs as

```
let array = [
  "Social Network: 1",
  "Tasks: 1",
  "Calendar: 1",
  "Journal: 1",
  "Business Contact Manager: 2"
];
```

I want convert this into an object as shown below:

```
{
  "Social Network": 1,
  "Tasks": 1,
  "Calendar": 1,
  "Journal": 1,
  "Business Contact Manager": 2
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It seems you meant that you want convert your array into a json object. Is that correct?

Comment: Iterate over the array, split every element over `:`, add a new key/value to the object according to these two parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the desired output:

```js
let array = ["Social Network: 1", "Tasks: 1", "Calendar: 1", "Journal: 1", "Business Contact Manager: 2"];

let result = array.reduce((r, c) => {
  let [k, v] = c.split(":");
  r[k] = Number(v);
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could build a valid JSON and parse it.

```js
var data = ["Social Network: 1", "Tasks: 1", "Calendar: 1", "Journal: 1", "Business Contact Manager: 2"];
    result = JSON.parse('{"' + data.join(',"').replace(/:\s/g, '":') + '}');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each string to a split `[key, value]` array, where `key` is the portion to the left of the `:` and `value` is the number to the right of the `:`. You can then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build an object from your key-value pair arrays:

```js
const array = ["Social Network: 1", "Tasks: 1", "Calendar: 1", "Journal: 1", "Business Contact Manager: 2"];

const res = Object.fromEntries(array.map(str => {
  const [a, b] = str.split(': ');
  return [a, +b];
}));
console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, if you can't support `Object.fromEntries()`, you can use `Object.assign()` instead by mapping to an object and then spreading the mapped objects into the arguments of `.assign()`:

```js
const array = ["Social Network: 1", "Tasks: 1", "Calendar: 1", "Journal: 1", "Business Contact Manager: 2"];

const res = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(str => {
  const [a, b] = str.split(': ');
  return {[a]: +b};
}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = [
  "Social Network: 1",
  "Tasks: 1",
  "Calendar: 1",
  "Journal: 1",
  "Business Contact Manager: 2"
];

const desiredObj = array.reduce((acc, currentItem) => {
  let arr = currentItem.split(":");
  acc[arr[0]] = Number(arr[1]);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(desiredObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is perfect for this:

```js
let arr = ["Social Network: 1", "Tasks: 1", "Calendar: 1", "Journal: 1", "Business Contact Manager: 2"]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, c, _, __, [k, v] = c.split(': ')) => 
    (acc[k] = Number(v), acc), {})

console.log(result)
```

Or how about this strange one:

```js
let arr = ["Social Network: 1", "Tasks: 1", "Calendar: 1", "Journal: 1", "Business Contact Manager: 2"]

const result = Object.assign(...arr.map((el) =>
    Object.fromEntries([el.split(': ').map((v, i) => i%2 ? Number(v) : v)])))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is of concern, go with this "classic" `for` loop solution. It is the fastest solution and quite considerably (up to 30%).

```
let array = ["Social Network: 1", "Tasks: 1", "Calendar: 1", "Journal: 1", "Business Contact Manager: 2"];
let result = {};

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let item = array[i];
  let pair = item.split(':');
  let key = pair[0];
  let value = parseFloat(pair[1]);
  result[key] = value;
}

console.log(result);
```